# fetching promise breaks in setInterval

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, router

So i'm a student in computer science , i'm kinda newbie , i ran into a problem that i couldn't solve ,
so i want to fetch from my bdd mongo every x seconds , and show the result in the html.
i have a function called getItems that does that for me , it works perfectly , hence when i try to set call it with setIntervel it works ! but only for 30 or 40 seconds and then breaks.
this is my code :

```
setInterval(getItems , 1000 ) ; 


const getItems = async () => {
  const requestOptions = {
    method :'GET',
  };
  const response = await fetch('/user/listed', requestOptions);
  const response2 = await fetch('/user/me', requestOptions);
  items = await response.json(); 
  owned = await response2.json() ; 
   
  if (response.ok && response2.ok) {
    // delete all the old values in listed 
   var e =document.getElementById("listed") ; 
   var child = e.lastElementChild ; 
   while (child){
     e.removeChild(child) ; 
     child = e.lastElementChild ; 
   }
   // delete all the old values in boughts 
   var e2 =document.getElementById("bought") ; 
   var child2 = e2.lastElementChild ; 
   while (child2){
     e2.removeChild(child2) ; 
     child2 = e2.lastElementChild ; 
   }
    // adding new values 
    for (var key in items ){
     
      
      const node = document.createElement("li");
      const textnode = document.createTextNode(items[key].name + " : " + items[key].price);
      node.appendChild(textnode);
      node.setAttribute("id", items[key]._id)  ; 
      const buy = document.createElement("button") ; 
      const buytext = document.createTextNode("buy") ; 
      buy.setAttribute("id", items[key]._id) ; 
      buy.setAttribute("onClick" , "buy(this.id)")
      buy.appendChild(buytext) ; 
      node.appendChild(buy) ; 
      document.getElementById("listed").appendChild(node);


    }
    // adding new values 
    for (var o in owned.bought){
      
      const node = document.createElement("li");
      const textnode = document.createTextNode(owned.bought[o].name + " : " + owned.bought[o].price);
      node.appendChild(textnode);
      node.setAttribute("id", [o]._id)  ; 
      document.getElementById("bought").appendChild(node);
  }

  }
}
```

and here is a picture of the error :
[image]

Thank you in advance !

here is my backend , the user/listed and user/me routes actually are :

```
module.exports.me =
  async (req, res) =>  {
    const user = await User.findById(req.userId);
    console.log(user);
    console.log(req.userId);
    res.status(200).json(user);
  }

  module.exports.listed =
  async (req, res) =>  {
    const listed = await Listed.find();
    console.log(listed);
    res.status(200).json(listed);
  }
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Are you asking why you get 403 back from the server?  If so, then we need to see the server code, not the client code.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes that is my question , well my code work perfectly without the setinterval , but there are no updates so i don't think it's the backend problem , also it works like that for 40seconds or more then it stops working and i think it's because the promise doesn't work well with the setinterval and that the setinterval breaks it at some time .

Comment: Do you have access to the server-side code?  It's possible that the server is rate limiting you and won't let you repeatedly send multiple requests every second.  I don't see any reason to believe this is a client-side problem.  You can do a simple experiment by just changing the interval timer to 20 seconds and see how long it runs then.

Comment: @jfriend00 but if you want to see my code it's a simple find of bdd of listed items and the user in the collection

Comment: ```module.exports.me =
  async (req, res) =>  {
    const user = await User.findById(req.userId);
    console.log(user);
    console.log(req.userId);
    res.status(200).json(user);
  }

  module.exports.listed =
  async (req, res) =>  {
    const listed = await Listed.find();
    console.log(listed);
    res.status(200).json(listed);
  }```

Comment: Well, 403 comes from the server so something in the server is manufacturing that error code.  Nothing we can figure out here by looking at the client code.  Need to see the overall server code to understand where the 403 comes from.

Comment: Multi-line code in a comment is not readable.  If required, you can add it to the end of your question and then refer to what you added in a comment.

Comment: i m a little bit of a newbie , can you tell me where i maybe find the rate limite ? cuz i m working on half already implemented code

Comment: Without seeing any of the server code, I would have no idea where rate limiting would be.  Probably in some middleware that is installed.  I'd suggest you run my experiment of making the timer less often and see if that changes things.

Comment: there are middlewares yes , can you tell me how the syntax of a limitation be ? how does it look like ?

Comment: No, can't tell you what to look for in code we can't see other than reading comments for clues or looking at packages being imported.

Comment: alright , thank you for your help ^^

Answer (score -1):

You are having cors errors, you said you have a node server? there is a cors modules try downloading it and installing it on your Node server. You should look into OWASP and CSP headers and their corresponding values

Also you may need to add headers to your requests:

```
require('dotenv').config();

app.use(cors());

app.use(middleware.setResponseHeaders)

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', ['*']);

 res.append('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff');

 res.append(

 'Strict-Transport-Security',

 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains',

 );
 res.append('Referrer-Policy', 'no-referrer');

 res.append(

'Content-Security-Policy',

'default-src * data: blob: "self" wss:* ws:* https://*; script-src 
"unsafe-inline" "unsafe-eval" blob: data: "self"; style-src data: blob: 
"unsafe-inline" "self" https://*; connect-src data: blob: "unsafe- 
inline" "self" https://*;',

);
res.append(

'Authorization',

'Bearer bjhf86uygbiluhgvyujkilu8y79iyuygvuyili8ygvuybkuliygvu jkun87yuhygvuyjk78ygyuiyg9v8iubyuo8pyhguyvhbjhgyibhkjlnihjpup8hguyhbjhiygyuhioguhgybukhigyhbjhoyiguybkjhlihouighbkjnihugyhvbjnkjihbjnbhjnhbjnuh=',
);

next();

});
```

Comment: How can this be CORS errors when it works the first several requests and then starts failing only after a number of successes?

Comment: You need to remember that set Intervals and setTimeout  are asynchronous also. Have you tried promise.all()?  Also if your requests are taking longer than 1 second a day you have an endless loop setup you will eventually blow the stack. Try recursion or callbacks. Only send the next request when the first has been resolved.